# Convex function approximation of the infinity norm

Tags: inequality, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, self-learning, infinity

I proved that the function $g(x)=\underset{\mu\in\mathbb{R}^n}{\mathrm{inf}}\big\{||\mu||_{\infty}^2-\frac{1}{\beta}||x-\mu||^2_2\big\}$ (with $\beta >0$) is convex. Now, I need to use it to approximate $f(x)=||x||^2_{\infty}$. More specifically, I need to show that $$\frac{\beta}{n}g(x) \leq f(x) - g(x) \leq \beta g(x).$$

I thought that maybe I could say $g(x)\leq ||\mu||_{\infty}^2-\frac{1}{\beta}||x-\mu||^2_2$ for all $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and then plug in some convenient $\mu$, but this didn't get me anywhere. I also checked that $f(x)=||x||^2_{\infty} \leq ||x||^2_2$ (didn't help much). I tried using the triangle inequality for the term $||x-\mu||^2_2$, but I don't think this helps either. I'm probably overthinking this one.

Comment: Are $\mu$, $u$ supposed to be different?

Comment: @RishiSonthalia my mistake, thank you for noting that

Comment: The following two facts might be helpful. First,

$$ \frac{1}{n}\|x\|_2^2 \le \|x\|_\infty^2 \le \|x\|_2^2. $$

Second, 

$$\|a-b\|_2^2 = \|a\|_2^2 + \|b\|_2^2 - 2a^Tb.$$

Comment: @RishiSonthalia I feel like the first one has to be helpful, but I don't really know how to use it. Do you think I should start with $g(x)\leq ||\mu||^2_{\infty} - \frac{1}{\beta}||x-\mu||^2_2$ and then apply the inequality? I've been trying that but it doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: @RishiSonthalia I'm now trying to do it this way: $\frac{\beta +n}{n}g(x) \leq \frac{1}{n} ||x||^2_2 \leq ||x||^2_{\infty} \leq ||x||^2_2 \leq (\beta + 1)g(x)$. Is this closed to what you were thinking?

Comment: or maybe using convexity (which i've already shown)?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that this is convex in the first place, since this is the inf-conv of a convex function with a strongly concave function... Are you sure that proof of convexity is right?